# How does Javascript's engine design affect user data structure implementations on worse case?

Tags: javascript, object, time-complexity, computer-science, implementation

Take, for instance, a JS web engine that implements associative arrays (objects) by using hash tables. but as we know hash tables have worse case O(n) because collisions are inevitable.

Suppose I begin to develop a new data structure using Javascript, a data structure such as LinkedList that has worse case O(1) for insert/delete. But since I implement it with object/array. Then it must be true that my implementation is also at minimum worse case O(n) as well.

I'm aware that this engine optimizes very well, and a good hash function will generate O(1) on average. However, I just want to confirm my realization that this isn't all as straightforward as the textbook says so. or is it?

I suppose at the root of all data structures implements with an array, since the access is always O(1), then shouldn't all data structures be built with an array without intermediary structures? also, the dynamic array still has delete O(n) cant that be the same problem that can trickle down just like my earlier example?

is this where the benefit of using a low-level programming language is better than using a high-level language? Such that low level there isn't so much abstraction and the textbook complexity numbers can actually match?

apologize if my ideas are all over the place.

Comment: Please clarify the paragraph _“I suppose at the root of all data structures implements with array, […]”_. Traditional array access is constant because every element has the same size, so, given an index, you’d just need a lookup at a memory location of _index · itemSize_. But, of course, JavaScript “Arrays” aren’t traditional arrays; they’re closer to hashmaps, _but_ optimized by modern engines. In contrast to arrays, hashmap lookup isn’t done the same way arithmetically (_“green” · itemSize_ doesn’t make sense). Deleting hashmap keys is O(1) since no reindexing happens.

Comment: Sorry but what is the actual question here? This seems like an open ended discussion of compilers as it pertains to optimizations of data structures as well as how much flexibility languages surface in their standard libraries.

Comment: I think you're putting too much emphasis on a single metric: time complexity. Time complexity is just one of many tools you can employ to reason about algorithms. It's not the be-all-and-end-all goal of all data structure and language decisions. TC defines the scalability of operations, but it says nothing about practical usage in the real world where constant (and many other) factors matter, and that's the domain that language designers are ultimately concerned with. Voting to close as too broad -- please narrow this discussion down to a single, specific question with a concrete use case.

Comment: Even within TC, so what if the worst case is terrible? That doesn't automatically mean it isn't still the best way to solve your problem. A few examples are Quicksort, insertion sort and Simplex. If the hash tables are designed well to eliminate collisions, pivots in QS are chosen well, and insertion sort is run on mostly-sorted arrays and so forth, the penalty of the worst case scenario isn't usually a problem in practice. Hash tables have to be pretty poorly designed to hit an O(n) access. You can (usually) trust the smart folks who are working on these languages. Don't prematurely optimize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But since I implement [my custom data structure] with object/array. Then it must be true that my implementation is also at minimum worse case O(n) as well.

No. Your linked list does not use an object with `n` keys anywhere. You'll have a

```
const linkedListNode = {
   value: …,
   next: null,
};
```

but even if this *was* implemented using a HashTable with `O(n)` worst-case member access, in your case `n=2`. There are not arbitrarily many properties in your object, just two. That's how you get back to `O(1)`.

> Is this where the benefit of using a low level programming language is better than using high level language? Such that low level there isn't so much abstraction and the textbook complexity numbers can actually match?

No. Even in a lower-level programming language, you can begin to question the underlying abstraction. You think in C, an indexed array access in memory is constant time? No, since page faults and other caching shenanigans come into play.

This is why textbook complexity is always defined in terms of a [machine model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_of_computation). As long as you define object property access in your JavaScript execution model as constant-time (and it's a very reasonable assumption to do that! It closely resembles the real world), your numbers do apply to JavaScript code as well. Sure, you can try unravelling abstractions and analyse your high-level algorithms in terms of the primitives of a lower level, but there's no point in doing that. It's precisely why we have these abstractions in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

"associative arrays (objects) by using hash tables" -> Javascript objects are complicated and are much more than just "it's a hash map".  I don't know the exact technical details but I think they change to hash map after a certain amount of values are stored in them, along with that they also store metadata which is used on other algorithms like `Object.keys` to automatically sort the keys after they've been pulled out of the hash map.  Again I don't know the technical details but I do know that, it's not straight forward.

"as we know hash tables has worse case O(n) because collisions are inevitable" -> It depends on what hashing you're using, but more than that even if collisions are inevitable it's not correct to just claim "it's worse case O(n)" and leave it at that because the probability of it being O(n) logarithmically declines to 0, the chances of it finding a collision time after time again and again is extremely unlikely, so while it can perhaps find a collision that doesn't effectively describe the time complexity.

"it must be true that my implementation is also at minimum worse case O(n) as well" -> Not correct, you're speaking about two different things.  If you build a linked list each node will be connected to the next node using a heap reference, which has nothing to do with javascript objects.  Iterating through an entire linked list will be O(n) but that's because of having to iterate over every next node, not because of anything with objects or hashes.

"worse case O(1) for insert/delete" -> This is only true if you have the reference to the node where you want to insert/delete it, otherwise you'll have to search through it before insertion/deletion.  But that's exactly the same in javascript.

"then shouldn't all data structure be built with array without intermediary structures" -> Most data structures I know (like a list, stack, queue) are implemented on top of a normal array.  The ones that aren't (like a binary tree, dictionary/map or a linked list) are not implemented on an array because it wouldn't really make sense.  For example the whole point of using object references with a linked list is so that you can directly insert/delete something, using an array under the hood would just defeat the entire point of using a linked list when you're specifically trying to take advance of the object references.

"also dynamic array still has delete O(n) cant that be the same problem which can trickle down just like my earlier example" -> Not necessarily because when you wrap things inside an object and use an internal array inside, you can add metadata, indexes, hashes, things stored outside of the array (private to the object) and all sorts of other things to speed up and keep track of things on that array.  So the complexity of what's used internally doesn't just automatically spill over to using it in another object.  But you do need to be careful, like if you use a list then the inner workings of it in languages like C# is that it will double the internal array when you try to add more elements to it after it's full, this can result in a lot of memory waste.

That being said the use case for javascript is in 99% of cases not "optimize this by another 10ms", javascript is used because of its non IO blocking nature, streaming, async/await reactive programming and it's rapid speed of development, it's also used 90% for web communication, not some highly optimized graphics engine.  So there's very very few edge cases where you need over 9000 complexity optimizations, feature development, code readability, maintainability, things like that are a much bigger deal in JS in general.  Along with that in most use cases you aren't going to request 1m data records from your DB using JS, usually like 50 that you want to display on a page and for that you'll use the DB to optimize your query, there's hardly ever any need for using such large data structures in any JS development (or web development in general).  It's a lot better to pull what you need and to request more or continuously stream what you need to the client.  So a lot of the data structures (like a binary tree) aren't really relevant to things in JS unless it's a very specific use case.